# Como tratar as chamadas de funções no php

Tags: php, funções

Tenho com problema relacionado as funções no php, Basicamente o usuário pode tentar acessar um função dentro do php dinamicamente, se a função exite ela é executada, mais caso não exita ela retorna  **Uncaught Error: Call to undefined** eu queria saber como verificar se a função não exite usando php para poder mostrar uma msg personalizada tipo 'A função não exite'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claro, voce pode validar que uma função exista.

Pode usar isso:

```
<?php
  //O parâmetro é o nome da sua função:
  if (function_exists('imap_open')) {
   echo "Las funciones de IMAP están disponibles.<br />\n";
  } else {
   echo "Las funciones de IMAP no están disponibles.<br />\n";
  }
?>
```

Fonte: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.function-exists.php.

Comment: Bgd, tinha procurado mais não tinha achado essa publicação.